# How do I combine multiple Average calculations based on multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I'm trying to calculate the average # of days it takes to close a ticket based on the type of report.

I figured out how to do this for any 1 type of report with the following query:

```
SELECT

CONVERT(DATE,SubmitDate) as 'Date'
,SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, SubmitDate, DateClosed)) / COUNT(*) as 'Report1Avg'

FROM Table1

    WHERE Status = 'Closed'
        AND ReportType = '1'

GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,SubmitDate)
```

But, I want to have the averages for all different types of reports.  I am trying to get the result set to look like the following:

```
Date Submitted  Report1Avg  Report2Avg  Report3Avg  Report4Avg
9/1/2015             5          10          11          NULL
9/2/2015           NULL         22           3           5
9/3/2015            1            3          NULL        NULL
```

Here is the table:

```
ticket  SubmitDate  ReportType  Status  DateClosed
  1      3/7/2014       NULL    Closed  8/18/2014
  2     3/17/2014       1       Closed  3/19/2014
  3     3/17/2014       3       Closed   4/1/2014
  4     3/18/2014       3       Closed   4/1/2014
  5     3/18/2014       3       Closed   4/1/2014
  6     3/19/2014       4       Closed  3/19/2014
  7     3/25/2014       4       Closed  3/25/2014
  8     3/25/2014       2       Closed  3/31/2014
  9     3/25/2014       NULL    Closed  3/31/2014
 10     3/25/2014       1       Closed  3/31/2014
```

I tried using UNION but didn't work.  Creating a VIEW also did not work.

I found some similar posts, but they do not involve averages.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: So you want an average by Type and Submit date ?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the desired result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT submitdate
    ,reporttype
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, SubmitDate, DateClosed)) NUMBER_OF_DAYS
INTO #temp
FROM table1
WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY SubmitDate,reporttype 

SELECT submitdate
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 1 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM #temp t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report1Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 2 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM #temp t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report2Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 3 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM #temp t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report3Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 4 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM #temp t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report4Avg
FROM #temp t1

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Or with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW AVG_REPORT AS 
SELECT submitdate
    ,reporttype
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, SubmitDate, DateClosed)) NUMBER_OF_DAYS
FROM table1
WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY SubmitDate,reporttype
```

Then:

```
SELECT submitdate
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 1 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM AVG_REPORT t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report1Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 2 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM AVG_REPORT t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report2Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 3 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM AVG_REPORT t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report3Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 4 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM AVG_REPORT t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report4Avg
FROM AVG_REPORT t1
```

It's also possible to use common table expressions (CTE) like this:

```
WITH
BASE AS ( 
SELECT submitdate
    ,reporttype
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, SubmitDate, DateClosed)) NUMBER_OF_DAYS
FROM table1
WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY SubmitDate,reporttype
)

SELECT submitdate
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 1 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM BASE t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report1Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 2 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM BASE t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report2Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 3 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM BASE t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report3Avg
    , CASE WHEN reporttype = 4 THEN (SELECT t2.NUMBER_OF_DAYS FROM BASE t2 WHERE t1.submitdate = t2.submitdate AND t1.reporttype = t2.reporttype) END Report4Avg
FROM BASE t1
```

Comment: This creates the result set that I am looking for, but is there a way to do this without creating a temp table?  Perhaps creating a view first?  I've been trying to do it on my own..but keep running into errors.

Comment: Edited my original post an added the code for a view. You first have to create a view and then you can the result set that you want with the latter code.

Comment: This is very close to what I was trying to achieve.  Thanks so much for your help hatsjie!

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to fix your `group by` clause:

```
SELECT
   CONVERT(DATE,SubmitDate) as 'Date',
   AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, SubmitDate, DateClosed)) AS 'Report1Avg',
   ReportType
FROM Table1
   WHERE Status = 'Closed'
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,SubmitDate), ReportType
```

If you want results formatted per your example, use `PIVOT` statement.

Comment: The result set does not show the Average days for the other types of report.